# Grant table pass on other users in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Is there any way how I could grant table that was created and granted to me by the other user to someone else? I tried "grant all on table_name to user" and my colleague is not able to grant this table to someone else.

Answer (score 4):

In oracle, you can use WITH GRANT OPTION for the same.

The owner of an object can grant it to another user by specifying the **WITH GRANT OPTION** clause in the GRANT statement. In this case, the new grantee can then grant the same level of access to other users or roles.

```
-- Owner of table1 is schema1
GRANT SELECT ON table1 TO Schema_2 WITH GRANT OPTION;
-- Schema2 can grant the same privileges to another schema
-- execute from Schema2
GRANT SELECT ON Schema_1.table1 TO Schema_3;
```

Hope, this will be useful to you.

Cheers!!